# Enabling RSA Toolbar in IE8

Tags: browser-addons, internet-explorer-8, toolbar

OS - Win7 Utlimate 64 bit
I have installed the RSA security toolbar used to VPN into my corporate network. I can see that RSA Toolbar is enabled in the Manage Add-Ons window. However I do not see the toolbar when I right-click in the toolbar section in IE. The add-on manger says that the toolbar is loaded but I cant get it to show in the toolbars section

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is a toolbar and not a button?  I've seen some plugins/bho which aren't actually a toolbar but just a single button.  If it is a button right click go to customize and check if it's listed there.

Comment: yes. The Add in manager lists it as a Toolbar